# Azure SQL Sync is a resource drain on laptop despite frequency setting

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

We have a SQL server running on a development laptop and would like to we'd like to deploy multiple laptops and use Azure Sync to distribute changes to each user.  Performance is too slow to have a remote SQL database with our current application -- that's a separate issue.  Speed isn't critical and I don't anticipate collisions between users.  I set the update to 12 hours and conflict resolution to member win.

Everything seems to be working as intended except the Microsoft SQL Data Sync 2.0 Windows service process is continuously consuming 2%-5% of the CPU and streaming data at about 80 kbps continuously.  I'm worried this will drain the batteries when the laptops are in the field.  Is there a better way to do this?

Here's the resource utilization from the Azure database.  I stopped the sync at some point to see if the frequency setting would automatically restart it (it does not).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own sync application based on your needs. [This](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sync/2010/08/31/sql-server-to-sql-azure-synchronization-using-sync-framework-2-1/) and [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1591.sync-framework-sql-server-to-windows-azure-sql-database-synchronization.aspx) resources provides you a good guidance. Below you will see a sample application.

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;

using System.Text;



using System.Data.SqlClient;

using Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServer;

using Microsoft.Synchronization.Data;

using Microsoft.Synchronization;



namespace SQLAzureDataSync

{

    class Program

    {

        public static string sqlazureConnectionString = "Server=[Your SQL Azure Server].database.windows.net;Database=AdventureWorksLTSQLAzure;User ID=[Your SQL Azure User Name]@[Your SQL Azure Server];Password=[Your SQL Azure Password];Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;";

        public static string sqllocalConnectionString = "Server=(local);Database=AdventureWorksLT2008;Trusted_Connection=True";

        public static readonly string scopeName = "alltablesyncgroup";



        static void Main(string[] args)

        {

            // Test if input arguments were supplied:

            if (args.Length == 0)

            {

                System.Console.WriteLine("Please enter an argument.");

                System.Console.WriteLine("Usage: SyncTest.exe -setup");

                System.Console.WriteLine("       SyncTest.exe -sync");

            }

            else if (args[0] == "-setup")

                Setup();

            else if (args[0] == "-sync")

                Sync();

        }



        public static void Setup()

        {

            try

            {



                SqlConnection sqlServerConn = new SqlConnection(sqllocalConnectionString);

                SqlConnection sqlAzureConn = new SqlConnection(sqlazureConnectionString);

                DbSyncScopeDescription myScope = new DbSyncScopeDescription(scopeName);



                DbSyncTableDescription Customer = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable("Customer", sqlServerConn);

                DbSyncTableDescription Product = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable("Product", sqlServerConn);



                // Add the tables from above to the scope

                myScope.Tables.Add(Customer);

                myScope.Tables.Add(Product);



                // Setup SQL Server for sync

                SqlSyncScopeProvisioning sqlServerProv = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(sqlServerConn, myScope);

                if (!sqlServerProv.ScopeExists(scopeName))

                {

                    // Apply the scope provisioning.

                    Console.WriteLine("Provisioning SQL Server for sync " + DateTime.Now);

                    sqlServerProv.Apply();

                    Console.WriteLine("Done Provisioning SQL Server for sync " + DateTime.Now);

                }

                else

                    Console.WriteLine("SQL Server Database server already provisioned for sync " + DateTime.Now);



                // Setup SQL Azure for sync

                SqlSyncScopeProvisioning sqlAzureProv = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(sqlAzureConn, myScope);

                if (!sqlAzureProv.ScopeExists(scopeName))

                {

                    // Apply the scope provisioning.

                    Console.WriteLine("Provisioning SQL Azure for sync " + DateTime.Now);

                    sqlAzureProv.Apply();

                    Console.WriteLine("Done Provisioning SQL Azure for sync " + DateTime.Now);

                }

                else

                    Console.WriteLine("SQL Azure Database server already provisioned for sync " + DateTime.Now);



                sqlAzureConn.Close();

                sqlServerConn.Close();

            }

            catch (Exception ex)

            {

                Console.WriteLine(ex);

            }

        }



        public static void Sync()

        {

            try

            {



                SqlConnection sqlServerConn = new SqlConnection(sqllocalConnectionString);

                SqlConnection sqlAzureConn = new SqlConnection(sqlazureConnectionString);

                SyncOrchestrator orch = new SyncOrchestrator

                {

                    LocalProvider = new SqlSyncProvider(scopeName, sqlAzureConn),

                    RemoteProvider = new SqlSyncProvider(scopeName, sqlServerConn),

                    Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.UploadAndDownload

                };

                Console.WriteLine("ScopeName={0} ", scopeName.ToUpper());

                Console.WriteLine("Starting Sync " + DateTime.Now);

                ShowStatistics(orch.Synchronize());



                sqlAzureConn.Close();

                sqlServerConn.Close();

            }

            catch (Exception ex)

            {

                Console.WriteLine(ex);

            }

        }



        public static void ShowStatistics(SyncOperationStatistics syncStats)

        {

            string message;



            message = "\tSync Start Time :" + syncStats.SyncStartTime.ToString();

            Console.WriteLine(message);

            message = "\tSync End Time   :" + syncStats.SyncEndTime.ToString();

            Console.WriteLine(message);

            message = "\tUpload Changes Applied :" + syncStats.UploadChangesApplied.ToString();

            Console.WriteLine(message);

            message = "\tUpload Changes Failed  :" + syncStats.UploadChangesFailed.ToString();

            Console.WriteLine(message);

            message = "\tUpload Changes Total   :" + syncStats.UploadChangesTotal.ToString();

            Console.WriteLine(message);

            message = "\tDownload Changes Applied :" + syncStats.DownloadChangesApplied.ToString();

            Console.WriteLine(message);

            message = "\tDownload Changes Failed  :" + syncStats.DownloadChangesFailed.ToString();

            Console.WriteLine(message);

            message = "\tDownload Changes Total   :" + syncStats.DownloadChangesTotal.ToString();

            Console.WriteLine(message);

        }

    }

}
```